# OpenGL cannot find uniform with glGetUniformLocation for second uniform

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, uniform

Me and a friend of mine are doing some 3d-programming, and we're trying to get out a pointlight. We're are trying to access a uniform for our light's position in the vertex shader but it doesn't get found.

Here is some code:

```
GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
glUseProgram(program);

rotationLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program,"vRotationMatrix");
if(rotationLoc != -1)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(rotationLoc,1,GL_TRUE,&world.rotationMatrix[0][0]);

LightLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "vLightPos");
if (LightLoc != -1)
    glUniform3fv(LightLoc, 1, LightPos);
```

As you can see we do the same thing for our rotation matrix first. It works for the rotation matrix, while it doesn't for LightLoc.
The error line is: LightLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "vLightPos");
LightLoc returns -1, but it should return 2.

Our vertex shader looks (partially) like this:

```
uniform mat4 vRotationMatrix;
uniform vec3 vLightPos;
void main()
{
    color = vColor;
    oTexCoord = vTexCoord;
    gl_Position = vRotationMatrix * vPosition;
    lightPos = vLightPos;
}
```

Comment: what's the definition of lightPos?

Comment: We define lightPost according to:
out vec3 lightPos
In the vertex shader.

Comment: And is it overwritten later on? One usual reason to have -1 on a properly spelled uniform is that it has been optimized out (usually through dead-code removal).

Comment: Is `lightPos` being used by the fragment shader?

Comment: It's not used but we've defined it as an invariable in our frag shader. However, even if we do not send it as an outvector from vertex shader, it still does not work.

Comment: And to Bahbar: We actually had that problem when we first worked with the rotationmatrix, but we managed to fix it. We didn't do the same mistake with LightPos ^^

Comment: Brett's point was that if it's not used in FS, then the deadcode removal can potentially span the shader object boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Try to output the result of the shader compilation using the code under the comment check vertex shader:

```
GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
int InfoLogLength;



// Compile Vertex Shader
printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

// Check Vertex Shader
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    printf("%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
}
```

Maybe there are any warnings or errors.
The same you can use for the fragment shader compilation